# Is this true? If is, how can I prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

> $ (\forall x>1, \ \exists \delta) \ \frac{e^x}{1+x^n}<\frac{e^x}{1+\delta^n}$

I use this property to prove for $a>1, \int_0^a \frac{e^x}{1+x^n}\to e-1$ but I’m not sure that why this property is true.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the original question: $\int_0^{1} \frac {e^{x}} {1+x^{n}}dx\to \int_0^{1} e^{x} dx=e-1$ and $\int_1^{a} \frac {e^{x}} {1+x^{n}}dx\to 0$; you can apply DCT for both integrals since the integrand is dominated by $e^{x}$ which is integrable.

Comment: Always in every post..you outspeed me in typing...:p axaxax

Comment: Can I ask you the full character of DCT?

Answer (score 0):

You need $$1<\delta <x$$

$$\delta=(1+x)/2$$ works

Comment: Its right, but I need constant $\delta$ to applicate It to the integration